# Joystick Does not implement interface member

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'd like to have touch screen controls. One joystick to move the first-person player, and the other to look around.
[image]

Comment: Instead of posting a screenshot of text, *post the actual text*, along with what you have already tried/researched.

Comment: Also, make sure all of your interfaces are... you know... implemented. There is at least one method from one of them that you do not have in your class.

Comment: @NahuelIanni all interfaces are implemented with just mistake: OnPointerUP should be OnPointerUp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small typo mistake:

Change:

`OnPointerUP` to `OnPointerUp`

C# is case sensitive, and simply compiler cannot say you implemented `OnPointerUp`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm newbie and need help.